# How make the same hole in two Form's on remote screen (client side), based on area drawn on server side?

Tags: delphi, screen-resolution, delphi-10-seattle, rect, paintbox

I have the following code and want draw the same hole in two Form's on remote screen (client side), based on area drawn on server side.

I have the same Form (**Form3**) in both sides (server and client) that is a "mirror" where i'm  drawing a area that must stays inside this same form on client side.

> The **Form3** in server side have *50%* of max `AlphaBlend` value, this is necessary to see remote screen behind **Form3**.

---

> *Before all, i want say that i'm receiving the remote screen on server side and  and mouse click positions works like expected*.

Then this is my trouble:

[image]

The following code produce the result showed on image above. I think that this code is right but is missing align this hole with the **Form3**.

Someone could help with this? sorry if this is a bad question, but this is all my actual trouble and i tried express all in this question of better way that i'm able.

This is all relevant code:

*Server side:*

**Form2** (where i see the remote screen):

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
 Unit1;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  Panel1: TPanel;
  CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
  ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
  Image1: TImage;
  PaintBox1: TPaintBox;
  procedure PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  procedure PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      X, Y: Integer);
  procedure PaintBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  procedure PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
    FSelecting: Boolean;
    FSelection: TRect;
    pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4: Integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin

  if CheckBox1.Checked then
  begin
    FSelection.Left := X;
    FSelection.Top := Y;
    FSelecting := true;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm2.PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
begin

  if FSelecting then
  begin
    FSelection.Right := X;
    FSelection.Bottom := Y;
    pbRec.Invalidate;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm2.PaintBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin

  if CheckBox1.Checked then
  begin
    FSelecting := false;
    FSelection.Right := X;
    FSelection.Bottom := Y;
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;

    FSelection.NormalizeRect;
    if FSelection.IsEmpty then
    begin
      // None selection was made on PaintBox
    end
    else
    begin
      pos1 := FSelection.Left;
      pos2 := FSelection.Top;
      pos3 := X;
      pos4 := Y;
    end;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm2.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked then
  begin
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Rectangle(FSelection);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket;
begin
  Socket := TCustomWinSocket(Form1.LV1.Selected.SubItems.Objects[0]);
  if CheckBox1.Checked then
  begin
      Socket.SendText(intToStr(pos1) + ';' + intToStr(pos2) + ';' +
        intToStr(pos3) + ';' + intToStr(pos4));
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form3 := TForm3.Create(Self);
  Form3.Show;
end;
```

Form2 **.DFM**:

```
object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = -1
    Top = 0
    Width = 773
    Height = 89
    Anchors = [akTop]
    BevelEdges = [beLeft, beRight]
    ParentDoubleBuffered = False
    TabOrder = 0
    end

object ScrollBox1: TScrollBox
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 765
    Height = 472
    HorzScrollBar.Smooth = True
    HorzScrollBar.Tracking = True
    VertScrollBar.Smooth = True
    VertScrollBar.Tracking = True
    Align = alClient
    TabOrder = 1
    object Image1: TImage
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Width = 1362
      Height = 621
      AutoSize = True
    end

object PaintBox1: TPaintBox
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Width = 1362
      Height = 621
      Align = alClient
      OnMouseDown = PaintBox1MouseDown
      OnMouseMove = PaintBox1MouseMove
      OnMouseUp = PaintBox1MouseUp
      OnPaint = PaintBox1Paint
      ExplicitWidth = 1364
      ExplicitHeight = 622
    end
```

**Form3** (the "mirror" Form that also is the same on client side), this Form is centralized according of remote screen resolution:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
 ...

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Image1: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure CreateParams(var pr: TCreateParams); override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

uses 
 Unit1;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyString: String;
  Splitted: TArray<String>;
begin
  MyString := Form1.LV1.Selected.SubItems[6]; // Resolution of remote screen
  Splitted := MyString.Split(['x']);

  Self.Left := (Integer(Splitted[0]) - Self.Width) div 2;
  Self.Top := (Integer(Splitted[1]) - Self.Height) div 2;
end;

procedure TForm3.CreateParams(var pr: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  pr.WndParent := Form2.Handle;
  pr.ExStyle := pr.ExStyle or WS_EX_TOPMOST or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
  pr.ExStyle := WS_EX_TRANSPARENT or WS_EX_TOPMOST;
end;
```

Form3 **.DFM**:

```
object Form3: TForm3
  Left = 328
  Top = 143
  BorderStyle = bsNone
  ClientHeight = 567
  ClientWidth = 526
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poScreenCenter
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 801
    Height = 569
    TabOrder = 0
    object Image1: TImage
      Left = 1
      Top = 1
      Width = 799
      Height = 567
      Align = alClient
      ExplicitLeft = 2
      ExplicitTop = 0
      ExplicitHeight = 447
    end

    object Label1: TLabel
      Left = 92
      Top = 69
      Width = 28
      Height = 13
      Caption = 'Nome'
      Color = clBtnFace
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
      Font.Style = []
      ParentColor = False
      ParentFont = False
    end
```

*Client side:*

**Form2** ("locker" Form):

```
unit Unit2;

private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.WndParent := Application.Handle;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TOPMOST or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
  Params.ExStyle := WS_EX_TRANSPARENT or WS_EX_TOPMOST;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  windowstate := wsmaximized;
  Top := 0;
  Left := 0;
  Height := Screen.Height;
  Width := Screen.Width;
end;

{

Properties of Form2:

Align => alNone
AlphaBlend => True
BorderStyle => BsNone

}

end.
```

**Form3** (the same of server side):

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
 ...

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure CreateParams(var pr: TCreateParams); override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

uses 
 Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Left := (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - Self.Width) div 2;
  Self.Top := (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - Self.Height) div 2;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
end;

procedure TForm3.CreateParams(var pr: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  pr.WndParent := Form2.Handle;
end;

{

Properties of Form3:

Align => alNone
BorderStyle => BsNone

}

end.
```

**Receiving the area on client side:**

```
procedure CS1_Read(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
 X1, X2, Y1, Y2: Integer;
 List: TStrings;
 FormRegion, HoleRegion: HRGN;
 StrCommand: string;

begin

if Pos(';', StrCommand) > 0 then
begin

    List := TStringList.Create;
    try

      ExtractStrings([';'], [], PChar(StrCommand), List);

      Form3 := TForm3.Create(Form2); // The Form2 already was created and is showing

      X1 := Round(StrToIntDef(List[0], 0) - Form2.Left);
      Y1 := Round(StrToIntDef(List[1], 0) - Form2.Top);
      X2 := Round(StrToIntDef(List[2], 0) - Form2.Left);
      Y2 := Round(StrToIntDef(List[3], 0) - Form2.Top);


      FormRegion := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, Form3.Width, Form3.Height);
      HoleRegion := CreateRectRgn(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
      CombineRgn(FormRegion, FormRegion, HoleRegion, RGN_DIFF);
      SetWindowRgn(Form3.handle, FormRegion, true);

      FormRegion := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, Form2.Width, Form2.Height);
      HoleRegion := CreateRectRgn(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
      CombineRgn(FormRegion, FormRegion, HoleRegion, RGN_DIFF);
      SetWindowRgn(Form2.handle, FormRegion, true);

      Form3.ShowModal;
      Form3.Release;

    finally
      List.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Obviously you should apply an offset to either Form2 region or Form3 region. The offset would be the left/top of either Form2 or Form3, whichever is not the one you're cutting the region. Can't tell which one from the other one as I'm completely lost about the setup.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, thank you very much by your suggestion, this will could be useful. Like ou can see, the image attached on question show that the code seems is right, because when i draw the area on server side, is created a hole on client side exactly like expected (hole that show Mozilla Firefox icon). But the other hole of Form3 appear wrong :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side you have a semitransparent gray form (Form2) that has the size of the screen. On top of that form you have a opaque white form (Form3) centered on the screen. In `Form3` you have a rectangular hole at `Top = Y` and `Left = X` in coordinates of `Form3`.

I understand that your problem is that you want to draw a hole in Form2 that is aligned with the hole in Form3.

You need to convert the coordinate system of `Form3` to that of `Form2` with a simple addition:

```
Form2.Hole.Left := Form3.Left + Form3.Hole.Left;
Form2.Hole.Top  := Form3.Top  + Form3.Hole.Top;
```

That would align the holes. You seem to attempt something like that in your calculation, but you refer to `Form2.Left` and `Form2.Top` which is useless as they are both 0.

If I misunderstood your question and you actually would like `Form3` hole to be aligned with the `Form2` hole, then you would need to move `Form3` to top - left of the screen and not center it ...

... Or, considering your comment: *if i'm drawing on server side in a area far of `Form3` (client) for example more to left side of screen, draw only the hole of `Form2` and if i draw more to middle of screen, draw the both hole aligned* would be accomplshed by simply swapping the terms:

```
Form3.Hole.Left := Form2.Hole.Left - Form3.Left
Form3.Hole.Top  := Form2.Hole.Top  - Form3.Top
```

This converts the `Form2` coordinates to `Form3` coordintaes, which may become negative values (iow outside of the form) in situations like your example.

Adapting the above to your code, you need to **first deal with Form2 region** with the received `Form2.Hole` coordinates, then subtract `Form3` coordinates (`Left` and `Top`) from X1..Y2 and **then deal with Form3 region***.

```
  X1 := Round(StrToIntDef(List[0], 0) - Form2.Left); // Form2 props can be removed as hardcoded to 0
  Y1 := Round(StrToIntDef(List[1], 0) - Form2.Top);  // -"-
  X2 := Round(StrToIntDef(List[2], 0) - Form2.Left); // -"-
  Y2 := Round(StrToIntDef(List[3], 0) - Form2.Top);  // -"-

  FormRegion := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, Form2.Width, Form2.Height);
  HoleRegion := CreateRectRgn(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
  CombineRgn(FormRegion, FormRegion, HoleRegion, RGN_DIFF);
  SetWindowRgn(Form2.handle, FormRegion, true);

  X1 := X1 - Form3.Left;
  Y1 := Y1 - Form3.Top;
  X2 := X2 - Form3.Left;
  Y2 := Y2 - Form3.Top;

  FormRegion := CreateRectRgn(0, 0, Form3.Width, Form3.Height);
  HoleRegion := CreateRectRgn(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
  CombineRgn(FormRegion, FormRegion, HoleRegion, RGN_DIFF);
  SetWindowRgn(Form3.handle, FormRegion, true);
```

---

**Edit**

It appears counterintuitive that your `Server.Form2` isn't the same size as the screen (and therefore `Client.Form2`). But maybe I never really understood for what actual purpose the setup is used.

Anyway, with equally sized, centered `Form3`'s, but with different screen sizes at Server and at Client, you need to adjust the `Form3.Hole` coordinates at the client with half the difference of Server and Client screen extents, or, since the `Form3` forms are centered, you can calculate the horizontal and vertical correction like

```
ResolutionCorrectionX := Server.Form3.Left - Client.Form3.Left;
ResolutionCorrectionY := Server.Form3.Top - Client.Form3.Top;
```

that you then add to the X- and Y-coordinates for `HoleRegion` of Form3.

```
X1 := X1 - Form3.Left + ResolutionCorrectionX; // and similar for X2, Y1 and Y2
```

Btw, just of curiosity, why are you using `Round()` for calculations based on integers?

Comment: thank you by your attention and answer. Could be better utilize the coordinates that already is drawn correctly on `Form2` (client side) and create the both hole on two Form's  (client side) in any position, independent where i draw on server side.

Comment: But as your example shows, `Form3` doesn't cover the area of the hole in `Form2`. Ergo, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: for example, i don't know if you noted, but the hole in `Form2` (the "Gray form" like you called) (client side) already is aligned correctly according with was drawn on server side (see the red square border around). Then exists the possibility that, already having this correctly to `Form2` (of client side), also have the same approach to `Form3` (client)? in others words, if i'm drawing on server side in a area far of `Form3` (client) for example more to left side of screen, draw only the hole of `Form2` and if i draw more to middle of screen, draw the both hole aligned.

Comment: In any position inside `Form3` that i'm drawing on server side, draw the both holes aligned on client side (`Form2` and `Form3`). This is what i need :-)

Comment: *`If I misunderstood your question and you actually would like Form3 hole to be aligned with the Form2 hole, then you would need to move Form3 to top - left of the screen and not center it.`* No, the `Form3` must be aligned to center of screen and not must b moved.

Comment: the both holes must be drawn on (`Form3` and `Form2`, respectively) and aligned according with mouse coordinates of server side.

Comment: Did you see I edited my answer according your earlier comment.

Comment: yes, i'm reading and will test yours suggestions. Only by curiosity, i also tested [**this**](https://pastebin.com/GqB2rubg), and the result produced is the hole of `Form3` aligned with mouse coordinates (server side) but the hole in `Form2` still is far (not aligned).

Comment: your first code example worked like i expected, except when i will make the 2 holes (in `Form2` and `Form3`), [**this**](http://prntscr.com/ly6umi) happens. This have solution?

Comment: I can't really say as I don't see your code and setup, maybe effect of a frame or border. I though both `Form2` and `Form3` are borderless.  Should become obvious if you look at the difference and relate that to frames, borders, bars etc on the forms.

Comment: ok thank you, your last edition solved the trouble of *"Form2 seems filling area"* showed on screenshot of my last comment, but not solved the trouble of alignment. I will try adjust subtracting or adding somes numbers. Eg: `X1: = X1 - Form3.Left + 4`; ...

Comment: i tested again and your last edition on answer not solved the trouble of [small diferences between holes](http://prntscr.com/ly6umi). The solution that i found was this: `X1 := Round(X1 - Form3.Left);
Y1 := Round(Y1 - Form3.Top + 20); // + 20
X2 := Round(X2 - Form3.Left);
Y2 := Round(Y2 - Form3.Top + 20); // + 20` but this have a trouble that is: **+ 20** (based in resolution of my Client computer where i'm testing). How make this same approach without add these fixed numbers? Because probably this not will work with others screen resolution.

Comment: thank you very by help until now! The section **Edit** of your answer is the solution to my last comment (about prevent "+20")? i made a last test and **+20** really worked to align the mouse coordinates with the holes on Client "Form2" and "Form3") in any screen resolution (of client). You is right when said on **Edit** of your  answer that *Form3* forms (on server and client) not are aligned, see [**this**](http://prntscr.com/lzyiwp) (this screenshot already was applied the solution of "+20" said before). There is a solution also to this (align Form3 server and Form3 client)?

Comment: **Continuation**... the screenshot linked on previous comment show that **Form3** of server is more to top of screen, while the same **Form3** on client is displayed more below. The **Form3** of server is my "mirror" to make the holes correclty on Form2 and Form3 respectively (on client side).

Comment: making a small modification on your code of **Edit**, this worked to me (in replacement to "+20" that i said before). See: `X1 := Round(X1 - Form3.Left - ResolutionCorrectionX);
            Y1 := Round(Y1 - Form3.Top - ResolutionCorrectionY);
            X2 := Round(X2 - Form3.Left - ResolutionCorrectionX);
            Y2 := Round(Y2 - Form3.Top - ResolutionCorrectionY);` **PS**: must replace **+** by **-**, then `- ResolutionCorrection`. OK! this trouble already is solved :-). But [**this**](http://prntscr.com/lzyiwp) still persists, see my last' comments about this case.

Comment: **Continuation**... See on my previous comment, on screenshot linked that exists a `ScrollBox` component on server, then in my tests if i adjust scrolling (manually) to down this can align both *Form3* forms (server and client). But will be that exists something that can align automatcally using Delphi code?

Comment: Glad you found that subtracting instead of adding solved your problem with the different sized screens. Now for the new problem (involving a scrollbox), we can't go on endlessly in the context of this question, but feel free to post a new question, exactly about that topic, and nothing more. That new question **must be self sustaining**, but can, in order to give some background info, refer to this q/a

Comment: ok thank you. I will create a new question about this new trouble.

Comment: *`"Btw, just of curiosity, why are you using Round() for calculations based on integers?`"*, you is right, **`Round`** is unecessary. and causes diferences on coordinates.